# How to use a dynamically created instance as a bean for use in Spring autowiring

Tags: java, spring

I have specific instances that I need to use for **autowiring** in an `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`. Below is the code that demonstrates the error. My case is much more complicated, of course, where the instances are determined at runtime. I discover the instances at spring configuration time which is why if the below coded worked, it would be fine. I tried but it throws `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` even though `ctx.getBean` is able to find it. What's the right way to accomplish this?

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;

class Scratch {
    static class MyClass {
    }

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Autowired
        private MyClass myClass;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass requiredInstance = new MyClass();
        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.refresh(); // Throws "BeanFactory not initialized..." on next line if this not here
        ctx.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("myClass", requiredInstance);
        // Also tried: ((DefaultListableBeanFactory)ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()).registerSingleton("myClass", requiredInstance);
        System.out.println(ctx.getBean(MyClass.class)); // Outputs "Scratch$MyClass@1804f60d"
        ctx.register(TestConfig.class);
        ctx.refresh(); // Throws "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'Scratch$MyClass' available:"
    }
}
```

Comment: When you `refresh` an `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`, it clears its underlying `BeanFactory` and creates a new one, and uses the new one to initialize beans. The `MyClass` bean won't be available to inject afterwards. It doesn't really make sense to have a `TestConfig` that has a dependency on a `MyClass` when no `MyClass` bean is available through the `@Configuration` hierarchy.

Comment: Okay, so is there some way for me to configure a bean factory type of thing that can inject the instances I need during the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here https://blog.pchudzik.com/201705/dynamic-beans/ . I had seen BeanFactoryPostProcessor mentioned elsewhere but they didn't show how to create the instance. This example showed using the factory mechanism that is what I needed.

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;

class Scratch {
    static class MyClass {
    }

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Autowired
        private MyClass myClass;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(TestConfig.class);
        ctx.register(DynamicBeanFactoryProcessor.class);
        ctx.refresh();
        System.out.println(ctx.getBean("myClass")); // Outputs "Scratch$MyClass@1804f60d"
        System.out.println(ctx.getBean(MyClass.class)); // Outputs "Scratch$MyClass@1804f60d"
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class DynamicBeanFactoryProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
        public <T> T createInstance(Class<T> c) {
            return c.cast(new MyClass()); // Create dynamic instance here
        }

        @Bean
        public DynamicBeanFactoryProcessor dynamicBeanFactoryProcessor() {
            return new DynamicBeanFactoryProcessor();
        }

        @Override
        public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
            ((BeanDefinitionRegistry)beanFactory).registerBeanDefinition("myClass",
                    BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(MyClass.class)
                        .setFactoryMethodOnBean("createInstance", "dynamicBeanFactoryProcessor")
                        .addConstructorArgValue(MyClass.class)
                        .getBeanDefinition());
        }
    }
}
```